# Prestashop - PHP fatal error after upgrade

Tags: php, prestashop, upgrade, fatal-error

After I upgrade Prestashop 1.5.1.2 to 1.6.1.6, Panel loaded successfully but the home page doesn't load.

I see this error in error logs:

> [Mon Sep 05 00:09:08 2016] [warn] [client 91.98.35.223] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function createTemplate() on null in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/classes/module/Module.php on line 2330

Comment: How you do the version upgrade?

Comment: We use 1-click upgrade module.

Comment: I see... bad idea... If you have backup, restore the backup. After you have to do the 'upgrade' with a new installation of PS, and to make a 'porting' of modules and theme (and all other things, products, orders, customers, etc) to the new installation. I'll suggest this way to upgrade prestashop, it's not easy, but it's the safest.

Comment: Add `debug_backtrace()` traces before this line to check which module is responsible of this error. Maybe you only have a problem with 1 module.